# KeyDown eventlistener not working after giving focus to textbox (C# Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, textbox, focus

I am wondering if there is a way to remove the focus off of a textbox so my keystrokes can be heard by the KeyDown eventlistener.

So far I have tried disabling the textbox, but that didn't fully remove the focus from the Textbox, since I could hear the windows error sound every time I would press space.

Comment: Did you check KeyPreview property of the form is set to true?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to handle the KeyDown event on the textbox itself, either using the same handler as the event for the [I assume] form you are trying to catch, or one catering to key events on the textbox

`txtUsername.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(textBox1_KeyDown);`

or if you must remove focus, you need to pass focus to another element e.g. a label

`this.ActiveControl = label1;`